# Why is it showing the error "the type or namespace 'Students' could not be found?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, list

On the click of the button I'm writing this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Students> student = new List<Students>()
        {
            new Students {FirstName= "Ram", LastName= "Gol"},
            new Students {FirstName= "Ran", LastName= "Gom"},
            new Students {FirstName= "Rao", LastName= "Gon"},
            new Students {FirstName= "Rap", LastName= "Goo"}
        };

        IEnumerable<Students> empQuery = from s in student
                       where s.FirstName.Length ==3
                       select s.FirstName;
        foreach (var stud in empQuery)
        {
            Button1.Text = stud;
        }
```

And I'm using System.Collection.Generic also. But I'm getting error of

> the type or namespace name 'Students' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Because it doesn't exist maybe? There is not nearly enough information here to even guess what's going on.

Comment: Have you defined the Students class somewhere?

Comment: Where do you have your `Students` class? Seems like it is not in your current scope.

Comment: Where is `Students` defined? Are you sure it's not `Student`?

Comment: `Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` is going to be your first clue. Try right clicking the class name with the red, squiggly underline, and see if the "Resolve" section suggests adding a `using` statement that would import the namespace with the class `Students`. If not, check that you didn't incorrectly pluralize as suggested above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed it and I was scratching my head over something silly. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks

Comment: if you click on the underlined word (students, in this case) and press ctrl + period, it'll look in the rest of your solution for matching classes. If there aren't any, itll suggest creating the class for you.

Comment: If you google ".net type or namespace could not be found", pretty much every single result on the first page would answer your question.  You'll get a warmer reception on SO if you do your own research first (that's probably why your question is being downvoted).  Something to keep in mind, to be a good-stackoverflow-citizen.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the Class is defined in the current project skip to step 4.
2. Make sure that the assembly where Students is defined is in the projects [reference folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (or that if it exsits that it is not a broken reference). If it is not there then add it.
3. If the reference is invalid, delete and re-add it by either pulling in a project reference or browsing to the location of the assembly. It will most likely be in the projects section of add reference.
4. If the reference is valid, put a [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) directive which specifies the Students namespace so it can be used.